# How many ways to arrange a group of 10 R's and 10 D's?

Tags: combinatorics

Given 10 letter R's and 10 letter D's, how many distinct sequences of length 20 can be formed? A justification of your answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about binomial coefficients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have decided on which places you want to place the D's, you know the entire sequence, right? This means the problem reduces to the number of possible positions of the $10$ D's, which is nothing else than the number of subsets of order $10$ in the set $\{1,...,20\}$, and per definition, this is ${20\choose 10}=184756$.

If that is a bit too little (I was assuming basic knowledge of combinatorics), you will want to read about binomial coefficients

Comment: Ah, I was completely over-analyzing this problem. Thanks!